# Any option available to limit subform to show only top 10 updated records in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to write query(For a subform) which shows only five of the recently added records in a table, You got any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort you query like you need it, then go to the Properties of your Query under **View > Properties** and set the property *Top Values* to **5**. In SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 5 Column1 FROM Table1 ORDER BY Column1
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure if i look at the right place. Could you explain the steps please?

Comment: Go in the ribbon menue to **Create > Query Design**. Chose your table and column with the right sort order. Then go to the **Design Ribbn Tab > Property Sheet**. Now the propertys of the query appear on the right side. In this properties look for **Top Values** and write **5** in it.